# shortcut not properly work in context menu submenu

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

In my application i have context menu like

```
ADD    Ctrl+1
EDIT   Ctrl+2
DELETE Ctrl+3
EXPORT -> Excel Ctrl+4
          PDF   ctrl+5
          CSV   Ctrl+6
```

In this context menu add,edit,delete shortcut coding is working when press the shortcut keys in form by excel,pdf,csv shorcut doest not work it. if show sub menu and press shortcut its working correctly. How work the shortcut of sub menus from form itself?

Comment: How are you implementing the shortcut functionality? Please, post the code.

Comment: @varocarbas during design time. In toolstripitem property shortcutkeys

Comment: I see... Bear in mind that the properties of each control/sub-control are applied when the given control is used. If you want something working generally (independently upon the selected element) you shouldn't work at control level. In this case, I understand that you don't want to create a global hook (e.g., triggering ADD every time CTRL+1 is pressed independently upon the program currently selected); but just something at the program level. In that case you should think about when you want the shortcuts to work (e.g., focus on main form) and write the code in the corresponding event(s).